# algorithm to create a circle in a 2D array EDIT: diamond would be okay aswel

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, geometry

I have a 2D in python that represents a tile map, each element in the array is either a 1 or 0, 0 representing land and 1 representing water. I need an algorithm that takes 2 random coordinates to be the center of the circle, a variable for the radius (max 5) and replace the necessary elements in the array to form a full circle.

```
x = random.randint(0,MAPWIDTH)
y = random.randint(0,MAPHEIGHT)
rad = random.randint(0,5)

tileMap[x][y] = 1 #this creates the center of the circle
```

how would I do this?

Comment: The main problem here is that you can't get anywhere close to a circle unless your radius is really large or your coordinates include decimals.

Comment: how would I do it if the radius was large enough, for example 25, I just need the algorythm

Comment: What would a circle of radius 5 or 10 look like on a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously said, you can use the definition of a circle, like so:

```
import math

def dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)

def make_circle(tiles, cx, cy, r):
    for x in range(cx - r, cx + r):
        for y in range(cy - r, cy + r):
            if dist(cx, cy, x, y) <= r:
                tiles[x][y] = 1

width = 50
height = 50

cx = width // 2
cy = height // 2
r = 23

tiles = [[0 for _ in range(height)] for _ in range(width)]

make_circle(tiles, cx, cy, r)

print("\n".join("".join(map(str, i)) for i in tiles))
```

This outputs

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000
00000000000000001111111111111111111000000000000000
00000000000000111111111111111111111110000000000000
00000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000
00000000000111111111111111111111111111110000000000
00000000001111111111111111111111111111111000000000
00000000011111111111111111111111111111111100000000
00000000111111111111111111111111111111111110000000
00000001111111111111111111111111111111111111000000
00000001111111111111111111111111111111111111000000
00000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000
00000111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000
00000111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000
00001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000
00001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000
00001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000
00001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000
00001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000
00000111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000
00000111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000
00000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000
00000001111111111111111111111111111111111111000000
00000001111111111111111111111111111111111111000000
00000000111111111111111111111111111111111110000000
00000000011111111111111111111111111111111100000000
00000000001111111111111111111111111111111000000000
00000000000111111111111111111111111111110000000000
00000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000
00000000000000111111111111111111111110000000000000
00000000000000001111111111111111111000000000000000
00000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Note that I deliberately used a rather large array and radius - this results in being able to actually see the circle a bit better. For some radius around 5, it would probably be pixelated beyond belief.

Comment: so when you run the function to create the circle, are x and cx, y and cy exactly the same?

Comment: because when I run this all I get is a parralellogram

Comment: Sorry, that's probably some unclear naming on my part. `cx` intends to refer to the centre x coordinate, same for cy, and x and y in the for loop iterate over positions.

Comment: A parallelogram? That's interesting.. Are you running all of my code, or have you incorporated it into yours?

Comment: I accidentally used the iterative variables in the for loop for cx and cy aswel

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set a coordinate to one if
`((x – h)(x - h)) + ((y – k)(y - k)) = r * r` is true.
`h` is the centre x coordinate and `k` is the centre y coordinate.

Comment: how would I implement this in a for loop for example?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Izaak van Dongen, just re-worked a bit:

```
from pylab import imshow, show, get_cmap
from numpy import random
import math

def dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)

def make_circle(tiles, cx, cy, r):
    for x in range(cx - r, cx + r):
        for y in range(cy - r, cy + r):
            if dist(cx, cy, x, y) < r:
                tiles[x][y] = 1
    return tiles

def generate_image_mask(iw,ih,cx,cy,cr):

    mask = [[0 for _ in range(ih)] for _ in range(iw)]
    mask = make_circle(mask, cx, cy, cr)
    #print("\n".join("".join(map(str, i)) for i in mask))
    imshow(mask, cmap=get_cmap("Spectral"), interpolation='nearest')
    show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image_w = 60
    image_h = 60
    circle_x = image_w/2
    circle_y = image_h/2
    circle_r = 15

    generate_image_mask(image_w,image_h,circle_x,circle_y,circle_r)
```